# Full page view on single scroll move to next section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried to create single scroll and move to next section, I have using javascript, It is not working fine, The window top distance not giving properly, I need to div fullscreen moved to next screen, Please without jquery, Please help

```js
   if (window.addEventListener) {window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;}

function wheel(event) {
    var delta = 0;
    if (event.wheelDelta) delta = (event.wheelDelta)/120 ;
    else if (event.detail) delta = -(event.detail)/3;

    handle(delta);
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = false;
}

function handle(sentido) {
    var inicial = document.body.scrollTop;
    var time = 500;
 var distance = 900;

  animate({
    delay: 0,
    duration: time,
    delta: function(p) {return p;},
    step: function(delta) {
window.scrollTo(0, inicial-distance*delta*sentido);   
    }
  });
}


function animate(opts) {
  var start = new Date();
  var id = setInterval(function() {
    var timePassed = new Date() - start;
    var progress = (timePassed / opts.duration);
    if (progress > 1) {progress = 1;}
    var delta = opts.delta(progress);
    opts.step(delta);
    if (progress == 1) {clearInterval(id);}}, opts.delay || 10);
}
```

```css
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
 .wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
 }

 section{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 .pg1{
  background: green;
 }

 .pg2{
  background: blue;
 }

 .pg3{
  background: yellow;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" id="myDiv">
 <section class="pg1" id="sec1"></section>
 <section  class="pg2"></section>
 <section  class="pg3"></section>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the height of the element and store it in distance variable, instead of giving it a static 900.

From this:

```
var distance = 900;
```

To this:

```
var distance = document.getElementById('sec1').clientHeight;
```